# Dynamically adding labels to axes core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Having values on y axis from 0 to 10 ; in real time if data having y-axis value as say 4.5 comes then is it possible to add label of 4.5 to the Y-axis created.So the Y-axis values 0 to 10 would not be disturbed and in between 4 to 5 there will be a label of 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis labeling is independent of the plot data and you can update it any time you want. How to add the "4.5" label depends on several factors, especially the labeling policy in use.

Comment: Thanks.Will try with the CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided as can be seen in the Axis Labelling Demo Example provided by Core Plot.Hope it works.